# How might I go about detecting phase changes in a sine wave of a certain frequency

Tags: signals, signal-processing, phase

I want to detect changes in the phase of a sine wave over time. I have a signal which is a sine wave in the KHz range and experiences random changes in it's phase. I want to detect these phase changes are count the occurrences. Ideally I would also be able to extract some approximate phase change in degrees for each occurrence. How might I go about that?

Comment: If the frequency `f` and sampling rate `fs` of the signal `x[n]` is known, compute `y1[n] = cos(2*pi*f*n/fs) x[n]` and `y2[n] = sin(2*pi*f*n/fs) x[n]` and pass each through a low-pass filter with cutoff around `f` (to eliminate artifacts at `2*f`) to get `z1[n]` and `z2[n]`. Then `atan(z2[n] / z1[n])` is the phase difference wrt `cos(2*pi*f*n/fs)` reference, from which phase changes can be seen. Now, if you are targeting a specific programming language this could become on topic for SO, else it would be better suited for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ or https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/40327/8952

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer on https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ linked here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/40327/8952